# How to make men relevant in a world where magic is gender specific to women?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

I have a question that might be considered broad. The setting is one where only women can use magic. All females can access it through some training, some being stronger than others. It takes the form of rituals and spells that may require multiple components and is time consuming. However, it is very powerful and forms the bedrock of society. It is often combined with technology to form a sort of magitech civilization. The question is how to make men relevant in a society like that? Have I made them completely useless? Does there need to be limitations on what magic can do?

Comment: Are you asking this on meta to see if it's too broad before asking on the main site? We have a [sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) for that.

Comment: You might be interested in a book called Changeweaver. Similar idea, might provide some ideas. I just found out while posting this that it is part of a trilogy... never knew that... it stands on its own.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say it is on topic, but it is still Too Broad in its current form (and, no, that's not intended as a pun). Kingledion had some questions. Those questions are key for me... when you ask questions about a magic system and its impact on the world -- physically, sociologically, etc -- I believe you need to pour your heart into the question with as much information as you can identify. Without that, each person who answers will have their own conception of your magic system, and the answers you get will be sweepingly different, and most of them not useful (I say having read many such questions).

**If you can nail down the details of your magic more, we can judge whether there's a role for men in this world. You need that to narrow the question.**

Answer (score 1):

My opinion: On topic and not too broad.

And as an advance comment, are you sure *all* women can use it? I mean if it requires training, then 99% of the world's women for most of history would not have had the free time to train, due to the need to farm, have babies, etc.